# How to test the xss protection of a rails view-helper method

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, xss

I have a helper method that takes a label and some data and formats it like this:

```
  def format_entry(labeltext, infotext)
    content_tag(:div, labeltext, class: 'dataleft') +
        content_tag(:div, infotext, class: 'dataright')
  end
```

The infotext can be user-generated, so I need to make sure that there is XSS protection. Therefore I have written a test:

```
  test 'no xss in format_entry' do
    label = "LBL"
    info  = "AA<BB"
    render text: format_entry(label, info)
    assert_select('div.dataright', "AA&lt;BB")
  end
```

This worked Rails 4.1. When I upgrade to Rails 4.2, the test breaks. 
It is because in 4.2 `assert_select` use Nokogiri, and it now evaluates the HTML-Entities. So it converts `&lt;` back to ">" automatically.

How can I test that the replacement is really happend?